# Multipart Request

Tags: retrofit, spring-data-rest

Using **Retrofit** to make request to a **spring-data-rest** instance, running into trouble sending multipart request.

**Retrofit**

```
@Multipart
@POST(URI)
void save(@Part("request[data][param][event]") Event event,
          Callback<Resource<Event>> callback);
```

**Spring**

```
@RequestMapping(value=URI, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<Event> addEvent(@RequestPart Event event) {
    ...
}
```

With this, I'm getting a **400 Bad Request**: *"Required request part 'event' is not present."*

Assuming the Event object has a String name & Bitmap image, what's the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost had it, the save method signature should be:

```
@Multipart
@POST(URI)
void save(@Part("event") Event event,
          Callback<Resource<Event>> callback);
```

Comment: this approach doesn`t work at me. server says:"Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present","path":"/backend/newimage". Put I have a @Part("file") param, so I don`t userstand

Comment: @Karoly could you make a Gist(gist.github.com) of your serverside and client code? I'd be willing to look over it.

Comment: Please find my question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121212/retrofit-and-multipart-image-uploading-with-http-400/31121642#31121642