# Retrofit and Multipart Image Uploading with HTTP 400

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit, bad-request

Im about to start crying, because Ive tried many solutions and topics, but it doesn`t work.

The issue:
I have to upload an String (it was a bitmap, but I have base64 coded) to our lovely server, so I have created a background Thread in Android to do it, and calling the backend. I get a HTTP 400 error message, with the following message:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException","message":"Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present","path":"/backend/newimage"}.
```

My headers:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 24069
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA0JCgsK.......etc.....binary
```

I don`t see in headers the following part:

> enctype: "multipart/form-data”). 
>   and I don`t understand why, my retforit interce looks like this:

```
@POST("/newimage")
@Multipart
String uploadImageToIdea(@Query("id") String id, @Part("file") String file );
```

I don`t understand the error message, because I HAVE the file param here.

I had tried the following (didn`t work obviously:

- [Retrofit Multipart Upload Image failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28348269/retrofit-multipart-upload-image-failed)
- [Retrofit - @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317096/retrofit-body-parameters-cannot-be-used-with-form-or-multi-part-encoding) (added @Headers, in this case I had more header before my request, but didn`t changed anything.)

my code to call the backend (not the final version, but first let things make work :) ):

```
   new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MultipartTypedOutput file = new MultipartTypedOutput();
                    for (int i = 0; i < imagesToUpload.size(); ++i) {
                        Bitmap imageBitmap = imagesToUpload.get(i);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
                        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                        String bitmapString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        backend.uploadImageToIdea(submitIdeaResponse.getIdeaDetails().getId(), bitmapString);
                    }
                }
            }.start();
```

Note from my backend developer:

> You need to send a multipart request (enctype="multipart/form-data”).

So, can someone please help me out, why I have HTTP 400 with the error message above? What can I change in my code to make this call work ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use [TypedFile](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/mime/TypedFile.html) for sending file in Multipart.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/newimage")
String uploadImageToIdea(@Part("id") TypedString id, @Part("file") TypedFile file);
```

for more information [link](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: I had already tried this way, but tomorrow I`ll retry it. Thank you

Comment: HTTP 400, but I solved it ,please see my answer above

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue for some time. Understanding the working code below should help you resolve this.

**Retrofit**

```
@Multipart @POST("/gifts")
void save( @Part("gift") Gift gift,
           @Part("file") TypedFile file,
           Callback<Resource<Gift>> callback);
```

**Spring**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gifts", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody HttpEntity<Gift> addGift(
        @RequestPart Gift gift,
        @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {...}
```

Note Spring will use reflection to match part names with controller method parameters. So the parameter *file* should match part "file". You can always override this in Spring by adding the part name manually: **@RequestPart("file")**

**Example Call:**

```
service.save(gift, typedFile, new Callback<Resource<Gift>>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Resource<Gift> resources, Response response)
        {/*...*/}

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error)
        {/* ... */}
});
```

Tip; don't mix multipart request with query strings unless you want a headache. Matching parts with parts seems to work well from one platform to another.

Comment: Hey Xerosigma, so if Note Spring will use reflection to match part names with controller method parameters, I`m not good with TypedString ? Because there is no file param. I created my own TypedString with file param, but it didn`t worked.

Comment: Right. I think your real issue here is the overall use of TypedString. Just send a String part and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured out the solution:

```
                     for (int i = 0; i < imagesToUpload.size(); ++i) {
                        Bitmap imageBitmap = imagesToUpload.get(i);
                        try {
                            String fileNameWithPath = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "file_" + String.valueOf(i);
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileNameWithPath);
                            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, out);
                            out.close();
                            backend.uploadImageToIdea(submitIdeaResponse.getIdeaDetails().getId(), new TypedFile("multipart/form-data",new File(fileNameWithPath)));
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

and the retrofit interface is the following:

```
    @POST("/newimage")
    @Multipart
    String uploadImageToIdea(@Part ("id") String id, @Part("file") TypedFile file );
```

So I don`t base64Code the image and uploading from the memory, BUT saving into the cache dir and upload the file itself. Using TypeFile of Retrofit for it.

Comment: where we can find class TypesFile?